# SpringBoot and Html: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: html, ajax, web-services, spring-boot, cors

I am running into the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" when I am trying to run a .html file on my machine through Chrome. It is trying to access a SpringBoot web service I have running on localhost:8080.

I am able to get a result from the web service itself by calling it directly through Chrome, but trying to call the web service through the index.html gives me the access-control error.

I have also tried the Spring [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)  but I still come across the same issues.

**index.html**

```
<title>My Worst Enemy</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#run").click(function()
        {
            var summonerName = document.getElementById("summonerName");
            console.log(summonerName.value);

            $.ajax({ 
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/summonerName/" + summonerName.value,
                success: function(data){        
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="summonerName" id="summonerName" value="Zann Starfire">
    <button id="run">Run Summoner</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebController.java**

```
package com.myWorstEnemy.web.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class WebController
{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String helloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/summonerName/{summonerName}")
    public String summonerName(@PathVariable String summonerName)
    {
        return "The summoner name = " + summonerName;
    }
}
```

Why is this a cross-origin request? I'm running the index.html from my computer and I wouldn't think localhost is a different origin from the web page I'm running, but I'm clearly missing something.

Is there anything I can add to my index.html to enable the cross-origin request, or do I need to do it elsewhere?

Comment: Are you getting the file through your web app, or through the file system ? Is the url in chrome http://localhost/.../index.html or file://.../index.html ? file:// is a different domain, I think ; try origins='*'

Comment: The word *origin* doesn’t mean “same system” or “same environment”. The word *origin* has a very specific technical meaning; it means the combination of a scheme+host+port. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454#section-5. For the purposes of the same-origin policy, two origins match only if the combination of their scheme+host+port exactly match. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy So according to those rules of what an origin is, what you’re trying is a cross-origin request

Comment: I didn't really think about file:// being a different origin, but that makes sense. I just wasn't paying attention to how I was running the web page. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was loading my index.html through the file system. "file://.../index.html" was the url when I ran it in Chrome, which meant the origin wasn't localhost. As such, it gave me the error.

Replacing

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
```

with

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

worked. Thanks okaram for the suggestion.